# Why doesnt browser show favicon after deployment

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, favicon

I have a asp.net mvc web application an it uses some favicon.ico. Now when I move it to IIS 7, as an application, the favicon stops being presented even when I try to enter the full address to the favicon. The icon is still there; the full address works in the browser to find the icon alone, but not within the applications master page. The code is standard and same as on some others of my apps, but there it works.

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../Content/Images/favicon.ico" />
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/Site.js"></script>
</head>
```

Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I remember correctly, in Internet Explorer, the favicon needs an *absolute* URL.
If that doesn't help:

- Maybe IIS serves the icon file with the wrong content type? I think the correct one is `image/vnd.microsoft.icon`. See [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(WS.10).aspx) for a way to set up the content type in IIS 7.
- There are a number of additional hints [on this page](http://www.favicon.com/ie.html)

Comment: Downvoted because you are linking to experts exchange (a pay to view solution site).  You should be ashamed of yourself.

Comment: @Jacob hahahaha! Fair enough. No idea what made me link to EE, I don't usually do. I replaced it.

Comment: Scroll-to-view if you come from Google.

Comment: Removed Downvote.  @mplugjan: It's not just that the answer requires scrolling; it's the fact that Experts Exchange is the arch-nemesis of Stack Overflow.  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/whos-your-arch-enemy.html

Comment: @Jacob mmm, meh to the "arch enemy" part. The "we hate EE" meme has been taken to such extremes over on Meta over the years, I don't think it's a productive thing anymore.  Clearly one shouldn't link to their content because it's paywalled - but if they would abandon it tomorrow and make their content freely available, I would have no quarrel with them

Answer (score 6):

try changing your link tag to:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Content/Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Browsers are very finicky about favicons. They will not always retrieve them on a refresh and oftentimes they will skip them at will.

The best approach is to place your favicon in your document root so that tthe link is `/favicon.ico`. Also make sure it is a real Microsoft format .ICO icon file. Looking it up through a path with parent directories `..` - like you do here - is asking for problems.

There is no formal cross server and browser standard, for more information see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: The .. notation is here because of asp.net mvc. It has in some great properties, but when it comes to displaying images, it's hell.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<full path to favicon.ico>" />
```

as the first line after the`<head>`tag, this worked for me in Chrome and IE10 with IIS7.

Check to make sure your site doesn't have more than one DOCTYPE file for separating content types IE and Chrome. One way to find out is to check the source code to see if the favicon link is truly there under the`<head>`tag.

If all else fails, you may want to try clearing your browser cache and double check the file permissions for favicon.ico - it should have world Read access.